# Check if a string is ensembl gene id or not in python

Tags: python, ensembl

I have many `scRNAseq` datasets saved as `hdf5` files (hierarchical data format*), and when I open them keys sometimes are confused, so I need a way of determining from string values themselves whether the array contains `gene symbols` or `ensembl ids`. What would be a regular expression in python to check for it?

*, A database format for quickly accessing large amounts of data, which is accessed using `keys`. The format is quicker than pickle/unpickle and can be viewed via a hdf5 viewer, a bit of info is [here](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/whatishdf5.html)

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it myself actually, not that hard. I found `regular expression` for `ensembl ids` here:

https://www.biostars.org/p/99142/

And used the `re` package in `python`:

```
import re

ensembl_regexp = 'ENS[A-Z]+[0-9]{11}'

is_ensembl = np.all([bool(re.match(ensembl_regexp, gene)) for gene in gene_symbols])
    if is_ensembl:
        gene_symbols = list(f['ensembl_ids'])
```

Where `gene_symbols` is a `numpy` array that I need to check whether it has `ensembl ids`, and if yes, switch to using `gene symbols` which are going to be under `ensembl_ids` key due to a mistake of someone who made the `hdf5` dataset.

Comment: What kind of Ensembl IDs are matched by the second part of that regex? `ENS[A-Z]+[0-9]{11}` matches the standard Ensembl IDs, what does the rest do? It looks like it matches FlyBase IDs (`CG[0-9]+`), and all sorts of other things. For example, that regex would consider `CG1` or `ABC123bobbie` valid Ensembl IDs.

Comment: Not sure, that’s what I got from the ‘Biostars’ link that is present in the answer. Maybe ask the person who answered it on ‘Biostars’ ?

Comment: Is this your question originally? Did you test this solution? The regex matches all sorts of IDs, many of which are not Ensembl. I have edited your answer so that it only matches Ensembl IDs as the question asks for.

Comment: Of course, this is still not entirely correct since it will allow something like `ENSABCDEFGHIJKL12345678901` which is clearly not a valid ID.

Answer (score 2):

The [answer by terdon](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/4966/9750) is probably good enough, but some commenters have noted it will allow something like `ENSABCDEFGHIJKL12345678901`.

It's helpful to reference the official documentation of [Ensembl Stable Ids](https://uswest.ensembl.org/info/genome/stable_ids/index.html):

> Stable IDs are created in the form ENS[species prefix][feature type prefix][a unique eleven digit number]. For example a mouse gene might be ENSMUSG###########. This means that we can immediately tell from a stable ID what kind of feature they refer to and what species they are in. The prefixes are listed on our [prefix page](https://uswest.ensembl.org/info/genome/stable_ids/prefixes.html).

The two places I look first for regexes are identifiers.org and wikidata. If these are wrong, best to report that upstream. Here are their ensembl regexes:

The regex used by the [identifiers.org registry](https://registry.identifiers.org/registry/ensembl) (for any ensembl ID) is quite long:

```
^((ENS[FPTG]\\d{11}(\\.\\d+)?)|(FB\\w{2}\\d{7})|(Y[A-Z]{2}\\d{3}[a-zA-Z](\\-[A-Z])?)|([A-Z_a-z0-9]+(\\.)?(t)?(\\d+)?([a-z])?))$
```

Meanwhile Wikidata has this regex for an [Ensembl gene ID](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P594):

```
(ENS(|MUS|RNO)G\d{11})|(Y[A-P][LR]\d{3}[CW](-[A-G])?)
```